# How to reset the X rotational value of a directional light to 0 after it passes 360 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a day night cycle. I have that part down but I need to reset the X rotational value of the directional light to 0 after it passes 360 degrees because other code depends on the value being between 0 to 360.

I have tried using a few different methods for resetting the rotation. None have reset it so far. It continues rotating beyond 360 degrees. This is my current script.

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 lightRotation = Vector3.zero;
    public float degreePerSecond = .6f;
    Vector3 lightReset = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(lightRotation, Space.World);
        lightRotation.x = degreePerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

        if(lightRotation.x >= 360)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = lightReset;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lightRotation will never exceed 360 in this line:

```
if(lightRotation.x >= 360)
```

because it is not increasing between frames. It is just being set to a value that basically represents rotation delta. You should check your actual transform rotation:

```
if(transform.eulerAngles.x >= 360)
```

Also consider looking at [Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle.html) function. It may be better suited for your task.